# How to sync PostgreSQL database structures between schemas

Tags: postgresql, schema, multi-tenant

I'm building an application which will have many customers (200+) and we're thinking about using PostgreSQL schemas to separate them.

Now, my question is, when I make a change in one table (e.g. adding a column), how to I get all other schemas to sync their table structure to the desired one?

Or how do I look for this in the Internet? I haven't found much. Maybe I'm missing the right keyword?

Comment: You dont want have 200 schemas. Instead you add `costumer_id` to your tables.

Answer (score 3):

If you want replicate same structure you probably need use inherit

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-inherit.html

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    name            text,
    population      float,
    altitude        int     -- in feet
);

CREATE TABLE capitals (
    state           char(2)
) INHERITS (cities);
```

In this case you can create a `JhonCustomer` table based in the original `Customer` table. If `Customer` table change then `JhonCustomer` also change.

But again I still think you should add `custumer_id` to your tables instead of create 200 schemas

Comment: One of my coworkers has concerns about performance issues. Is this any slower than with schemas?

Comment: No guey. Schemas is just like store files in different folders. You dont gain performance for spliting a file in different folders.

Comment: Performance is absolutely a concern with this scenario, namely the fact that indexes are **not** inherited and that is a big deal.

Comment: @RustProofLabs If you read my comment I already suggest he shouldnt do it. But OP ask how he can do it and I suggest `inherit` as a  solution. I dont know what are the OP requiremnts because the question is very broad.

Comment: @MarcBackes To be clear I try to answer how you syncronize schemas. If you want improve perfomance for your application mutltiple schemas wont help you with that,  the same as multiple folders doesnt improve file access speed. If you want help with performance I sugest you create a different question with more information so we can help you with that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Beyond the issue with indexes and check constraints not being inherited, that option does nothing to help with objects like views or functions.  While the OP didn't explicitly mention views or functions it's silly to think there wouldn't be any, so inheritance is an incomplete option at best.

Comment: @RustProofLabs Again I dont know all the OP requirements. I have work with inherit tables and dynamic ddl to create the index and constrains automaticly. I can see you arent a fan but I just trying to give OP an option. In my case I use it with [partitions tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html) That have the advantage to allow you handle lot of data separating all by day. Maybe something like that also can work.

Answer (score 1):

[Row Level Security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) with a `customer_id` column would by how I approach this.
I've used this [model where you trust the application](https://schinckel.net/2017/12/20/django-multitenancy-using-postgres-row-level-security/) to handle setting the session variable for the right customer.  This really shouldn't change much in the application itself since the other approach would require the app to handle setting the client's schema.

To learn more about RLS, [CrunchyData](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/a-postgresql-row-level-security-primer-creating-large-policies) has some great info
as does
[this post by Caleb Brewer](https://medium.com/@cazzer/designing-the-most-performant-row-level-security-strategy-in-postgres-a06084f31945).

### Why not multiple schemas with table inheritance?

Navigating/exploring your database becomes tedious with so many schemas.  Regardless of the tool (`psql`, PgAdmin, etc), trying to review/find schemas in a list of 200+ is miserable.  This impacts your developers, admins and analysts, making every one of their lives less fun and less productive.  This greatly increases the cost of maintenance.

Second:  Performance!  Indexes on the parent table **are not inherited** by their children tables.  If you want an index on a column that's inherited by every schema you need to explicitly create those indexes in each schema's version of the table.  So one table needing 3 indexes on it now requires 200+ * 3 indexes.  Need to drop an index.... that's 200+ times you need to drop that index.

Control:  What happens when a dev creates a new table in a client schema "because this important client needs it right now?"  Finding oddities such as this become virtually impossible.  This is another area where cost of maintenance can increase exponentially.

If you insist on using one schema per customer, [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) probably won't help more than it hurts.

### Automation is best approach

If you need to deploy one schema per customer, automated deployment should be your goal.  Even if you choose to use RLS and keep all the data in one set of tables, automation should still be a high priority.  Tools like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) and [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) can be invaluable for this.  Using this approach you would write your DDL with the schema set as a parameter (variable) that is only populated at deploy-time.  This way each schema gets deployed as an exact version with *all objects* in your database, including indexes and check constraints on tables, views, and functions.